# Meteor: Access the context (template) data in rendered callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a template with `yield` section:

```
  {{>yield}}
```

In the `yield` I'm displaying form with fields filled with currently editing category data:

```
this.route('editCategory', {
    path: '/panel/category/:_id/edit',
    layoutTemplate: 'panelTemplate',
    template: 'editCategoryTemplate',
    data: function(){
        return Categories.findOne(this.params._id);
    },
});
```

There is a selectbox, (where I'm choosing the parent category) with couple of options. I'm selecting previously chosen option with script:

```
Template.editCategoryTemplate.rendered = function(){
    $('#categoryParent option[value="'+ this.data.parent +'"]').prop('selected', true);
};
```

And everything works fine, but after reload the page there is an error:

```
Exception from Deps afterFlush function: this.data is null
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this page may provide some help http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/TypeError_-_Cannot_read_property_nodeName_of_null

Comment: My guess is that the callback function on the rendered is called when the template instance is rendered but maybe the data are not retrieved yet so there is no `parent` available.

Comment: I have similiar guess - but how to solve this? How force Meteor to wait/retrieve this data? (it is already saved in Categories document collection)

Answer (score 1):

It is good idea to put guards:

Instead using `this.data.parent` write :

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
  var parentData = this.data && this.data.parent;
  if(parentData){
    $('#categoryParent option[value="'+ parentData +'"]').prop('selected', true);
  }
})
```